# while loop into in array

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

What am I trying to do is collect data from a while loop, store it into a variable. Then later in my code I see if some variable is equal to one of the values in the array and then to echo out the two other column values I got from the while loop but equal to the row that the value came from. I have tried a bunch different things and am so close but cant get it exactly.

```
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

$team[] .= "{$row['team']}";
$winslosses .= "({$row['wins']} - {$row['losses']})";
```

}
this returns something like

```
      $team = (bears, badgers, wildcats)
      $winslosses = ((42-24), (55-23), (32-21))
```

Then later in my code I want to see if its equal to a value in the array then echo $winslosses.

```
  if(in_array(bears, $team) ) {echo '$winslosses';}
```

This shows all the wins and losses from each team. I want it only show me the record of the bears.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What does your sql statement look like? First guess is that $query['wins'] should be $row['wins'] , and the same with losses. What is it currently displaying? Can you post the excerpt?

Comment: What's the question? It appears that you've got all the code that you need.

Comment: sorry I wrote that wrong and updated it... I want only the wins and losses from the team that is in the array. Right now next to the bears it shows Bears (42-24) (55-23) (32-21)... I only want the one that goes with the team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to get the index of an item in an array. You can then use that index when querying $winlosses:

```
$team = array(bears, badgers, wildcats);
$winslosses = array("(42-24)", "(55-23)", "(32-21)");

$key=array_search(bears, $team);
echo $winslosses[$key]
```

results in:

```
(42-24)
```

Comment: This is what worked for me and was the easiest. Thanks @jeff.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to store them in an associative array.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $winslosses[$row['team']] = "({$row['wins']} - {$row['losses']})";
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you currently have `$winslosses` as a string, not an array, so you can't easily pull out the win/loss record for just one team.

There are several ways you could do this. The one that seems easiest to me would be to put it together as one array up front.

Something like...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $teams[$row['team']] = "({$row['wins']} - {$row['losses']})";
}
```

Then later on...

```
if(array_key_exists("bears",$teams)) {
    echo $teams["bears"];
}
```

Or even better, store the wins/losses as a sub-array, so you have structured data that you can format however you want later on.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $teams[$row['team']] = array("wins" => $row['wins'], "losses" => $row['losses']);
}

echo $teams['bears']['wins']; // for example
```

Answer (score 0):

Use associative array:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

  $team[] = {$row['team']};
  $winslosses[$row['team']] = "{$row['wins']} - {$row['losses']}";

}
```

Then retrieve it like this:

```
 if(in_array(bears, $team) ) {
         echo $winslosses['bears'];
   }
```

As a matter of fact, if you do not need the names of the teams in a separate array, you can just use one associative array and then retrieve it.

```
if (array_key_exists('bears', $winslosses)) {
    echo $winslosses['bears'];
}
```